# Right command for Saving Spectrgram images in the drive

Tags: python, librosa, spectrogram

I try to save the generated spectrogram images in my drive But I am not able to save the exact spectrogram images.

```
from pathlib import Path
base_path = Path('/content/drive/MyDrive/Audio')
for wav_file_path in base_path.glob("*.wav"):
    print(f"WAV File: {wav_file_path}")
    x,sr=librosa.load(wav_file_path)
    mel_spectrogram=librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=x,sr=sr)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    plt.grid(True)
    fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,4))
    librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram, ref=np.max))
    fig.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Spec/spec.png')
```

But, it saves the image which is shown in below format instead of spectrogram images.

Comment: There is no "below format". It is unclear which format you desire, or how the result is wrong. If the data isn't actually PNG, which format is it? Or if it is in fact PNG but you want some other format, which format is that? See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].